# Accessing @PathVariable at class level

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Sample of simple controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/event/{id}")
public class EventController {

    @PostMapping
    public String attendEvent(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getEvent(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, only http request type changes in mappings. So, is there any way of avoiding re-consuming id? If not, why?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/event/{id}")
public class EventController {

    @PathVariable Long id; //doesn't work
    
    @PostMapping
    public String attendEvent() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getEvent() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot avoid reconsuming ids for two reasons:

1. You have defined your controller as a singleton, so you could imagine that you'd have some race conditions with concurrency if the field member "Long id" was changed for simultaneous requests. Theoretically, you could define the Controller with scope prototype, but I'm not recommending that.
2. The [PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation is defined with @Target(value=PARAMETER). This means you cannot apply it to fields like you have here.